# JPA unknown column alias in 'group statement'

Tags: java, sql, jpa

I got an error while running this query on java SQL but it works when I tested it on SQL editor

```
@Query(value = "SELECT l.loan, max(i.date) as dDate, tr.collecty, sum(i.expectedAmount) as amount,"
            + "(select CASE WHEN (br.stype = 'x') THEN br.idNumber ELSE br.np END as type from Bower br inner join Leds ld on br.id = ld.bowerId where ld.loan = :loan) as bId "
            + "FROM Loan l INNER JOIN Inst i ON l.loan = i.loan INNER JOIN TList tr ON l.loan = tr.loan WHERE l.loan = :loan GROUP BY l.loanId, tr.collecty, bId")
```

and got error

Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'bId' in 'group statement'

how to fix it?

Comment: @Eklavya well, its typo, it correct on my code

Answer (score 0):

The order of execution of group by is before the select in a query. So, at the time you group by bId, the select query is not executed yet and it won't recognize bId column or any alias that you specify at select.

Answer (score 0):

Since bId is a derived column, you can not perform aggregation using the column at the same level. You need to go one level above. Below code should work. However there is still a scope to improve the way aggregation is being performed.

```
@Query(value = “SELECT loan, dDate, collecty, amount, bId FROM (SELECT l.loan, max(i.date) as dDate, tr.collecty, sum(i.expectedAmount) as amount,"
            + "(select CASE WHEN (br.stype = 'x') THEN br.idNumber ELSE br.np END as type from Bower br inner join Leds ld on br.id = ld.bowerId where ld.loan = :loan) as bId ) "
            + "FROM Loan l INNER JOIN Inst i ON l.loan = i.loan INNER JOIN TList tr ON l.loan = tr.loan WHERE l.loan = :loan ) GROUP BY loan, dDate, collecty, amount, bId”)
```

Comment: well i got, org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ( near line 1. @ShantanuKher

Comment: if i add "SELECT NEW com..loan.service.dto.Response(loan, dDate, collecty, amount, bId)FROM (SELECT l.loan, max(i.date) as dDate, tr.collecty, sum(i.expectedAmount) as amount,"
            + "(select CASE WHEN (br.stype = 'x') THEN br.idNumber ELSE br.np END as type from Bower br inner join Leds ld on br.id = ld.bowerId where ld.loan = :loan) as bId"
            + "FROM Loan l INNER JOIN Inst i ON l.loan = i.loan INNER JOIN TList tr ON l.loan = tr.loan WHERE l.loan = :loan ) GROUP BY loan, dDate, collecty, amount, bId”)